# I tried to install Pupilfirst LMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpack-dev-server, rescript

I tried to install Pupilfirst LMS, I had difficulty in step

- Compile Rescript Code: yarn run re: build
- Output: Usage Error: could't find a script named "re: build".

And I also have difficulty in step

- Run Webpack Dev Server: yarn run wds
- Output: Usage Error: could't find a script named "wds".

is there any solution?

https://docs.pupilfirst.com/developers/development_setup

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a space between `re:` and `build`: `yarn run re:build`.

Also, when running a `yarn run script_name` command, make sure that your current directory contains a `package.json` file where the script `script_name` is defined.

In case of pupilfirst this file is in the root: https://github.com/pupilfirst/pupilfirst/blob/e41ffb8a57f4c59f7927056af324b5c283fb0038/package.json